# Understanding return statement with Db/Map JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
    return db
        .doneTodo
        .find({'victor._id': member._id})
        .then((userVictories) => {
            return {
                email: member.email,
                victories: userVictories.length
            };
        });
})).then((memberStats) => {
    console.log(membersStats);
});

db.doneTodo
```

is a Mongoose Schema. I have a question:

**Q:** Why do we need the "return" statement beside "db.doneTodo..."? Why isn't the second "return" enough?

**My reasoning:** Since we are applying map to each element we are applying this function:

```
{
                return db
                    .doneTodo
                    .find({'victor._id': member._id})
                    .then((userVictories) => {
                        return {
                            email: member.email,
                            victories: userVictories.length
                        }
                    });
            }
```

**And**

```
.then((userVictories) => {
                        return {
                            email: member.email,
                            victories: userVictories.length
                        }
```

Evaluates to

```
{
                                email: member.email,
                                victories: userVictories.length
                            }
```

**SO DOES:**

```
db
                        .doneTodo
                        .find({'victor._id': member._id})
                        .then((userVictories) => {
                            return {
                                email: member.email,
                                victories: userVictories.length
                            }
                        });
                }
```

Evaluate to

```
{
                                    email: member.email,
                                    victories: userVictories.length
                                }
```

Thus we return it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are partially correct. `.then()` returns a `Promise`, and if you return a value from within a `.then()`, it will effectively return `Promise.resolve(<value>)`.

So, indeed, the following code does return (or rather *resolve the promise with that object as the value*) the object.

```
.then((userVictories) => {
    return {
        email: member.email,
        victories: userVictories.length
    }
});
```

> Q: Why do we need the "`return`" statement beside "`db.doneTodo...`"? Why
>   isn't the second "`return`" enough?

You want to return the result to the `Promise.all()` function call, which will wrap all the resolved promise values in an array which is then resolved from the promise that the `.all()` function returns.

If you were to omit the top `return` statement, the code would still run, but if you chained the `Promise.all(...).then((arrayOfResults) => { ... })`, the `arrayOfResults` would contain a number of `undefined` values.